# ssis assign a value to a guid when null

Tags: sql, ssis-2012

I have the following expression in ssis

```
(ISNULL [rowguid]? (DT_WSTR, 255)"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000":[rowguid])
```

What I want is to assign that guid if there is null present. I just can't seem to get it working

Comment: I have the exact same problem. In TSQL you can insert a varchar that looks like a GUID into a UniqueIdentifier column but in SSIS it fails.

Comment: (DT_STR,50,1252) (ISNULL( [apuk_networkid]) ? "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" : (DT_STR,50,1252) [apuk_networkid]) != (DT_STR,50,1252) (ISNULL( [LK_apuk_networkid]) ? "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" : (DT_STR,50,1252) [LK_apuk_networkid])

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FInally got the answer via trail and error

```
  (DT_STR,50,1252) (ISNULL( [rowguid]) ? "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" : (DT_STR,50,1252) [rowguid]) != (DT_STR,50,1252) (ISNULL( [rowguid]) ? "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" : (DT_STR,50,1252) [rowguid])
```

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured this one out. You need to include "{" and "}" on the front and end of your default GUID. So for example, (DT_GUID) "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}".

A little frustrating, I tried "[]" but never even thought to try "{}".